# Why is AdWhirl showing no adds in my android App?

Tags: android, adwhirl

I just integrated adwhirl into my android app. 
Now I'm a little bit puzzled on how to ensure that ads are shown in my App.

I activated admob as the only ad serving network for now. 
After my app starts I get the following log output:

```
06-10 14:03:08.007: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Creating adWhirlManager...
06-10 14:03:08.014: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Locale is: de_DE
06-10 14:03:08.014: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Hashed device ID is: ...
06-10 14:03:08.022: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Finished creating adWhirlManager
06-10 14:03:08.389: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Prefs{...}: {"config": "{"extra":{"location_on":0,"background_color_rgb":{"red":40,"green":53,"blue":98,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":30,"transition":3},"rations":[{"nid":"706a61fa3ec446c7b016bfa9d39256d4","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":100,"priority":1,"key":"a14deaa0ed3f8f6"}]}
06-10 14:03:08.389: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881): ", "timestamp": 1307707109720}
06-10 14:03:08.389: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Using stored config data
06-10 14:03:08.389: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Received jsonString: {"extra":{"location_on":0,"background_color_rgb":{"red":40,"green":53,"blue":98,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":30,"transition":3},"rations":[{"nid":"706a61fa3ec446c7b016bfa9d39256d4","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":100,"priority":1,"key":"a14deaa0ed3f8f6"}]}
06-10 14:03:08.600: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Rotating Ad
06-10 14:03:08.600: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Dart is <91.2614682720399> of <100.0>
06-10 14:03:08.921: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Showing ad:
06-10 14:03:08.921: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881):     nid: 706a61fa3ec446c7b016bfa9d39256d4
06-10 14:03:08.921: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881):     name: admob
06-10 14:03:08.921: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881):     type: 1
06-10 14:03:08.921: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881):     key: a14deaa0ed3f8f6
06-10 14:03:08.921: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881):     key2: 
06-10 14:03:08.936: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(4881): Valid adapter, calling handle()
```

**Update** I also found this in the logs

```
06-10 14:45:34.546: ERROR/Ads(6010): ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions must be enabled in AndroidManifest.xml.
06-10 14:45:34.546: ERROR/Ads(6010): You must have INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.
06-10 14:45:34.764: ERROR/Ads(6010): ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions must be enabled in AndroidManifest.xml.
```

**/Update**

I use this code to integrate AdWhirl into my app:

```
    AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);

    AdWhirlTargeting.setAge(28);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setGender(AdWhirlTargeting.Gender.MALE);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("banking, credit, interest");
    AdWhirlTargeting.setPostalCode("93047");
    AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(true);

    adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, "my Key");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_adwhirl);

    layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, adWhirlLayoutParams);
    layout.invalidate();
```

This is the layout for the screen that should show the ads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#283562">

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/layout_adwhirl"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:background="@android:color/black"/>

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_above="@id/layout_adwhirl">

      contains the rest of the layout...

  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The adWhirlLayout however stays empty. How can I test if this is because no ads are served to me or because I did something wrong with integrating adWhirl?

Comment: looks fine to me. You sure you don't have any layout problem?

Comment: I added my layout, with this configuration the ad space is not visible because the adWhirl View has height 0 and width 0

Comment: I i set the width of the linearlayout containing the ads to a fixed size it justs displays a black area

Comment: Did you add admob jar to your libraries ?

Comment: Yes I added both libraries to the project

Comment: I found some more logs I addded them, see the update section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this line from the log showed the problem:

```
06-10 14:45:34.764: ERROR/Ads(6010): ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions must be enabled in AndroidManifest.xml.
```

The access network state permission is not optional for admob. If you want to use Admob you have to ask for this permission in your manifest file.

Add

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

to the manifest tag in your apps manifest.xml file.